# Qt - deploying on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, deployment, visual-studio-2013

I've built an application using Qt 5.3.1, its official Add-in for VS 2013 and, of course, VS 2013 itself (Update 3).
This is the specific Qt software I have installed:

- Qt 5.3.1 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2013, OpenGL, 557 MB)
- Visual Studio Add-in 1.2.3 for Qt5

Now, I am obviously talking about a development machine but I want to be able to deploy this program to other machines that haven't got either MSVC or Qt installed, "stock" Windows basically.
I've tried using the Depedency Walker to try and figure out the required depedencies (the right version of it too, x86) but the output is quite cryptic and there are a LOT of system DLLs that are indistinguishable one from another, I simply don't know which ones come with a default installation of Windows 7 and which ones with development tools that the target machine assuredly won't have. I did find the basic Qt DLLs using that tool, but for a lot of others I had to look elsewhere.
The installation tool I'm using is the Advanced Installer (trial version). I've also thoroughly read the manual found [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/windows-deployment.html).

The error I am getting when trying to run the executable on a target machine:

[image: error]

This is how the application's directory looks like when installed, with all of the dependencies I've managed to "collect" so far:

```
|-- root
    |-- imageformats
    |   |-- qdds.dll
    |   |-- qgif.dll
    |   |-- qicns.dll
    |   |-- qico.dll
    |   |-- qjp2.dll
    |   |-- qjpeg.dll
    |   |-- qmng.dll
    |   |-- qsvg.dll
    |   |-- qtga.dll
    |   |-- qtiff.dll
    |   |-- qwbmp.dll
    |   `-- qwebp.dll
    |-- platforms
    |   |-- qminimal.dll
    |   |-- qoffscreen.dll
    |   `-- qwindows.dll
    |-- icudt52.dll
    |-- icuin52.dll
    |-- icuuc52.dll
    |-- msvcp120.dll
    |-- msvcr120.dll
    |-- Qt5Core.dll
    |-- Qt5Gui.dll
    |-- Qt5Widgets.dll
    |-- AppBackend.dll
    `-- App.exe
```

Note that there are no "d" variants (Qt5Cored.dll, for example) of these DLLs since the source was built in Release mode. I will provide more info, if needed.

Comment: That could be why you're getting an error if your app depends on image plugins. You can use Dependency Walker to view what dependencies your dependencies have. For example, open qwindows.dll with Dependency Walker. But first, try [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) with your app running on your test machine to see your dependencies. It's much better. And take a look at this [Triple Boot article](http://www.tripleboot.org/?p=536). If you're having plugin problems, adding a qt.conf file can be good for troubleshooting.

Comment: @AndrewDolby If I do that, JPEG images in my app don't load so it obviously cannot find the required dll (qjpeg.dll, I guess) but it loads PNG images just fine. All of those images are embedded resources. Quite peculiar. I've also obfuscated the path to Qt's dir so I could test this properly. It works as is when I do that on my machine without doing the changes you proposed. MS technologies are probably the culprit, I think it is not enough to have C & C++ runtimes (msvcp120 and msvcr120). What else could be missing there, I simply do not know. I will try to follow your advice regarding tools.

Comment: I was incorrect: your imageformats folder was in the correct location at /root/imageformats.

Comment: @AndrewDolby I was once again reminded to read the Triple Boot article on the official Qt forums. The problem was that the msvcp120 and msvcr120 DLLs were 64-bit instead of 32-bit. Make your comment an answer and I'll accept it, if you want.